# which rails query/chain is better?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, chaining

I have a rails app with the models below. I have both assigned_tasks and executed_tasks for a given user. I would like to know which option is better for getting all the tasks (executed and assigned as well) for that given user.

task.rb

```
belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"
```

user.rb

```
has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assigner_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :executed_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "executor_id", dependent: :destroy
```

**Solution 1**:

task.rb

```
scope :completed, -> { where.not(completed_at: nil) }
scope :uncompleted, -> { where(completed_at: nil) }
```

user.rb

```
def tasks_uncompleted
  tasks_uncompleted = assigned_tasks.uncompleted.order("deadline DESC")
  tasks_uncompleted += executed_tasks.uncompleted.order("deadline DESC")
  tasks_uncompleted.sort_by { |h| h[:deadline] }.reverse!
end
```

tasks_controller:

```
@tasks = current_user.tasks_uncompleted.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
```

**Solution 2:**

task.rb

```
scope :completed, -> { where.not(completed_at: nil) }
scope :uncompleted, -> { where(completed_at: nil) }
scope :alltasks, -> (u) { where('executor_id = ? OR assigner_id = ?', u.id, u.id) }
```

tasks_controller

```
@tasks = Task.alltasks(current_user).uncompleted.order("deadline DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
```

Comment: The second is much better, although `Task.alltasks(current_user)` is pretty smelly. Having an `all_tasks` relation on `User` that achieves the same thing would be much cleaner, e.g. `current_user.all_tasks.uncompleted...`.

Comment: +1 for the 2nd option, -1 for the solution #2 with `Task#alltasks` which should probably be `Task.for_user(current_user) ...`

Comment: @MrYoshiji, you think the problem is only the naming with the second one?

Comment: yes but as Jordan said, in your controller and others places where you can use `current_user`, you should use something like `current_user.all_tasks.uncompleted` where `User#all_tasks` is a scope defined in `User` model returning either assigned or created Tasks (like Jordan posted in his answer). --- EDIT: Actually @Jordan sums up everything in his answer, I would do like he suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define an association on User that will return all of the Tasks associated by either `executor_id` or `assigner_id`:

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assigned_and_executed_tasks,
           ->(user) { where('executor_id = ? OR assigner_id = ?', user, user) },
           class_name: 'Task',
           source: :tasks
end

user = User.find(123)
user.assigned_and_executed_tasks
# => SELECT tasks.* FROM tasks WHERE executor_id = 123 OR assigner_id = 123;
```

Then you can do as you do in "Solution 2," but instead of the unfortunate `Task.alltasks(current_user)` you can just do `current_user.assigned_and_executed_tasks` (of course you could give it a shorter name, but descriptive names are better than short ones):

```ruby
@tasks = current_user.assigned_and_executed_tasks
           .uncompleted
           .order("deadline DESC")
           .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
```

Comment: I also need on other pages the executed_tasks and the assigned_tasks separately. Can not cause problems if I put there this 3rd association as well. Don get things a bit messy?

Comment: Having a third association does not cause any problems, nor does it incur any overhead. It makes your code less messy overall by making it more readable and letting you remove that `Task.alltasks` scope, which does the exact same thing but in the wrong place.

Comment: Having the 3 associations actually makes sense: "get me the Tasks where User X is assigned" ; "get me the Tasks where User X is the executor" ; "get me all the Tasks related to User X". You don't need less, you don't need more, just these 3.

Comment: If I use what you say I get uninitialized constant User::AssignedAndExecutedTask error (It's also not working in the console). Should not I do something in the task model as well?

Comment: I think you need to add the `class_name: 'Task'` option. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Almost there, but still can't figure it out: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column tasks.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."user_id" = $1 ... : SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."user_id" = $1 AND (executor_id = 1 OR assigner_id = 1) AND "tasks"."completed_at" IS NULL  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 will be the more efficient way of retrieving the records from your database. In most Rails apps, calls to the database are a frequent cause of bottlenecks, and in solution 2 you make one call to the database to retrieve all the records, but in solution 1 you make two calls to the database to retrieve the same information.

Personally, I also think this solution is much more readable, easily testable, and maintainable, so solution 2 is better in many ways beyond speed!